# How to get the reasoner to "start" with city A and get the rest of the cities that is linked by Transitive property

Tags: owl, protege

I am building an ontology in Protege. In this exemple I have 7 individuals of the "City" class (from "City_A" to "City_G" (North to South)). I want to create classes ('CitysNorthOf_D') that only shows the individuals of 'StartCity' (is a subclass of City), and all the individuals which are located north (above) of 'StartCity' (City_E, City_F and City_G). In the real ontology I have more citys and properties. This is just one example to show the issue:

[image: Class view]

[image: Property view]

[image: Individuals view]

Examples of object properties:

1. 'road': Transitive + Symmetric (but have no purpose for this issue)
2. 'south': Transitive (link one Individual 'City' to the Individual 'City' below current Individual. For example City_A have: south = City_B.
3. 'north': Transitive (same as 'south' but links the city above.

What I want to do are different classes that are looking for cities under different conditions(axioms). All using Transitive in properties to link cities together and all Classes 'start' from the Individual that have subclass 'StartCity'(from 'City'). 
With the help of properties that link different cities together (eg for link properties: south, north, road type, distance etc and for cities: size, type (city, village, suburb) etc).

Examples of classes and their conditions:

1. All cities located north from the start city.*
2. Same as above but only in two steps (all cities located two or less cities north of the start city.*
3. All cities that can be reached by motorway (have not added type of road type in this example).*
4. All cities that can be reached without going through a larger city (size).*

*= All classes start from *start city* marked with a subclass to city named 'Start_City'

Want these classes to work **independently** of each other. But when I do two classes with the following in "Equivalent To": "StartCity or City that south some StartCity", only one class works(last one).

I have tried the follow in "Equivalent to":

```
StartCity or City that south some StartCity
```

It shows the right Individuals in the list 'Instances' of the 'Description' view for the class.

**But...**
If I add a new class with the exact same axiom. The both classes do not work. Only the last one. The class work separately but not when other similar classes exist.

**I just want to use the axioms in the classes to do this.**

What do I wrong? Is it possible? Or have I misunderstood how to use axioms in classes or should I test the class in another way?

Comment: please fix all your typos like induvidual, mening, Symemetric, ontoligi - any spell checker of the browser should already show you that something is wrong with your text. Using markdown for formatting makes it also much more readable. And adding images directly instead of links ...

Comment: Sorry, can't add pictures directly to the page as I don't have enough 'points' (new).